# How can I determine the column type represented by a MySql .Net Connector's MySqlDateTime structure?

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-connector

DataColumn.DataType returns FullName = "MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime" regardless of the type of the column it represents, if it is either DATE, TIME, or DATETIME.

Clearly I can query the information_schema.columns table, though I'm hoping that the connector library stores this detail somewhere that I just can't find in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a quick look at the MySQLClient source code, I think your best choice is IDataReader.GetDataTypeName().  This is the underlying DBMS's name for the data type of a column.  For (a limited amount of) more info, see the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getdatatypename.aspx) and the [corresponding MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldatareader-getdatatypename) for this property.

Here's the source from MySqlDateTime.cs for this property, which looks promising:

```
string IMySqlValue.MySqlTypeName
{
 get
 {
  switch (type)
  {
   case MySqlDbType.Date: return "DATE";
   case MySqlDbType.Newdate: return "NEWDATE";
   case MySqlDbType.Timestamp: return "TIMESTAMP";
  }
  return "DATETIME";
 }
}
```

Here's another utility function you may want to borrow the code of, from MetaData.cs:

```
public static MySqlDbType NameToType(string typeName, bool unsigned,
  bool realAsFloat, MySqlConnection connection)
{
 switch (typeName.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
 {
  case "CHAR": return MySqlDbType.String;
  case "VARCHAR": return MySqlDbType.VarChar;
  case "DATE": return MySqlDbType.Date;
  case "DATETIME": return MySqlDbType.DateTime;
  case "NUMERIC":
  case "DECIMAL":
  case "DEC":
  case "FIXED":
   if (connection.driver.Version.isAtLeast(5, 0, 3))
    return MySqlDbType.NewDecimal;
   else
    return MySqlDbType.Decimal;
  case "YEAR":
   return MySqlDbType.Year;
  case "TIME":
   return MySqlDbType.Time;
  case "TIMESTAMP":
   return MySqlDbType.Timestamp;
  case "SET": return MySqlDbType.Set;
  case "ENUM": return MySqlDbType.Enum;
  case "BIT": return MySqlDbType.Bit;

  case "TINYINT":
            return unsigned ? MySqlDbType.UByte : MySqlDbType.Byte;
  case "BOOL":
  case "BOOLEAN":
   return MySqlDbType.Byte;
  case "SMALLINT":
   return unsigned ? MySqlDbType.UInt16 : MySqlDbType.Int16;
  case "MEDIUMINT":
   return unsigned ? MySqlDbType.UInt24 : MySqlDbType.Int24;
  case "INT":
  case "INTEGER":
   return unsigned ? MySqlDbType.UInt32 : MySqlDbType.Int32;
  case "SERIAL":
   return MySqlDbType.UInt64;
  case "BIGINT":
   return unsigned ? MySqlDbType.UInt64 : MySqlDbType.Int64;
  case "FLOAT": return MySqlDbType.Float;
  case "DOUBLE": return MySqlDbType.Double;
  case "REAL": return
    realAsFloat ? MySqlDbType.Float : MySqlDbType.Double;
        case "TEXT":
            return MySqlDbType.Text;
        case "BLOB":
   return MySqlDbType.Blob;
  case "LONGBLOB":
            return MySqlDbType.LongBlob;
        case "LONGTEXT":
            return MySqlDbType.LongText;
  case "MEDIUMBLOB":
            return MySqlDbType.MediumBlob;
        case "MEDIUMTEXT":
            return MySqlDbType.MediumText;
  case "TINYBLOB":
            return MySqlDbType.TinyBlob;
  case "TINYTEXT":
   return MySqlDbType.TinyText;
        case "BINARY":
            return MySqlDbType.Binary;
        case "VARBINARY":
            return MySqlDbType.VarBinary;
 }
 throw new MySqlException("Unhandled type encountered");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That might prove helpful for future projects. However almost all of my code is based around filling DataTable objects with DataAdapter.Fill() rather than using a DataReader.